# Trouble setting up Google Earth Engine API in RGEE package R. normalizePath cannot find python.exe

Tags: python, r, api, rgee

Hi Im new to stackoverflow, so apologies in advance if this is a basic question or if information on the problem is insufficient.

The Problem:
I am trying to setup the RGEE package in R. I have installed rgee and reticulate packages with dependencies. I then ran this line.

```
ee_install(py_env = "rgee")
```

After creating the Python Environment, I received this message and chose to proceed.

```
rgee::ee_install want to store the environment variables: EARTHENGINE_PYTHON 
and EARTHENGINE_ENV in your .Renviron file to use the Python path:
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\rgee\python.exe in future sessions.
```

This continues to install the earthengine-api successfully and suggests a restart. After which I receive this Warning message.

```
Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Users\XXXXX\.conda\envs\ee/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
```

After restarting, I run this:

```
Restarting R session...

> library(rgee)
> ee_check()
(*)  Python version
√ [Ok] C:/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe v3.6
√ [X] earthengine-api not installed
Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Users\XXXXX\.conda\envs\ee/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Users\XXXXX\.conda\envs\ee/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
3: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Users\XXXXX\.conda\envs\ee/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
```

Not sure where I am going wrong. I have restarted the session and R a few times and tried again but this problem persist. I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your folder contains spaces, the problem radicates there. If not, you can try installing the earth engine api manually with:

```
py_install( "earthengine-api==0.1.277", "rgee")
```